# Plural noun for things with a pair

Tags: singular-vs-plural

There are two containers connected with a thin sheet of plastic for keeping a pair of contact lenses. Should we call them (or it)

> Contact lenses cases

or

> A contact lenses case

or

> Contact lens cases

or

> A contact lens case

[image]

Comment: This is perhaps my  idiosyncrasy, but I'd use "a contact lens case."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single container to hold multiple items, both container and contained are singular. A matchbox, a briefcase, a bookshelf, a notebook, a sock drawer.

Glasses case is widely used, maybe because glass case would be confusing. Some people are not comfortable with this usage and say spectacle case instead.

The correct term is therefore

> a contact lens case

Comment: *Eyeglass case* may be more productive than *glass(es) case*. Or *case for my glasses*.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, according to Ngram, spectacle case >> eyeglass case for British English, but eyeglass case > spectacle case  for American English.  Odd, when the order is glasses >> spectacles > eyeglasses for both languages.

Comment: Yeah, just reporting on my own real life usage in the past few days to describe the object; (AmE). I expanded it to *case for my glasses* rather than say *glass(es) case*. It is weird  though, that many folks don't seem to know that *lens* is singular.